# C code, rewritten to use a Person struct without pointers

Tags: beginner, c, homework

I'm new to C and I have been assigned the task of converting some code that uses **structs with pointers** to code that **doesn't use pointers**. I would be interested to know if the code I have written is 'good' code and how I could improve it. Here is the code I have written which creates a Person struct then creates a few sample persons.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

typedef struct person Who;

struct person Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight) 
{

    Who w;

    w.name = strdup(name);
    w.age = age;
    w.height = height;
    w.weight = weight;

    return w;
}

void Print_person(Who w) 
{
    printf("Name: %s\n", w.name);
    printf("\tAge: %d\n", w.age);
    printf("\tHeight: %d\n", w.height);
    printf("\tWeight: %d\n", w.weight);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct person ryan = Person_create("Ryan McGovern", 37, 182, 67);
    struct person sandy = Person_create("Sandy McGovern", 32, 167, 49);

    printf("Ryan is at memory location: %p\n", &ryan);    
    Print_person(ryan);

    printf("Sandy is at memory location: %p\n", &sandy);
    Print_person(sandy);

    ryan.age += 2;
    ryan.weight += 4;

    Print_person(ryan);

    return 0;
}
```

**Prints out:**

```
Ryan is at memory location: 0x7fff52b7ea68
Name: Ryan McGovern
    Age: 37
    Height: 182
    Weight: 67
Sandy is at memory location: 0x7fff52b7ea50
Name: Sandy McGovern
    Age: 32
    Height: 167
    Weight: 49
Name: Ryan McGovern
    Age: 39
    Height: 182
    Weight: 71
```

---

Original code using pointers (from the book *Learn C the Hard Way* by Z. A. Shaw):

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <assert.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
>
> struct Person {
>     char *name;
>     int age;
>     int height;
>     int weight;
> };
>
> struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight)
>
> {
>
>     struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
>     assert(who != NULL);
>
>     who->name = strdup(name);
>     who->age = age;
>     who->height = height;
>     who->weight = weight;
>
>     return who;
> }
>
> void Person_destroy(struct Person *who)
> {
>     assert(who != NULL);
>     free(who->name);
>     free(who);
> }
>
> void Person_print(struct Person *who)
> {
>     printf("Name: %s\n", who->name);
>     printf("\tAge: %d\n", who->age);
>     printf("\tHeight: %d\n", who->height);
>     printf("\tWeight: %d\n", who->weight);
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char *argv[])
> {
>     struct Person *ryan = Person_create("Ryan McGovern", 37, 182, 67);
>
>     struct Person *sandy = Person_create("Sandy McGovern", 32, 167, 48);
>
>
>     // print them out and where they are in memory 
>     printf("Ryan is located at memory location %p:\n", ryan);
>     Person_print(ryan);
>
>     printf("Sandy is at memory location %p:\n", sandy);
>     Person_print(sandy);
>
>     // Make them age 20 years and print them out again
>     ryan->age += 20;
>     ryan->height -= 2;
>     ryan->weight += 4;
>     Person_print(ryan);
>
>     sandy->age += 20;
>     sandy->weight += 10;
>     Person_print(sandy);
>
>     // Clean up
>     Person_destroy(ryan);
>     Person_destroy(sandy);
>
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: You have to be really careful with this! `Who` has a pointer to allocated memory (a string), and you need to make sure it gets freed ONCE. Because you pass the object around by copy, you potentially have multiple copies of this pointer, but you still can free it only once. This is a memory ownership nightmare. You need to clearly define who owns the memory, such that when you pass the object around by copy it’s clear that you’re dealing with a copy and you don’t own the associated memory.

Comment: Not using `strdup` would solve the problem: you keep a copy of a pointer to memory owned by whoever calls `Person_create`. Or do as suggested below and copy the string into a staric array member of the object. But then passing by copy is more expensive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an interesting problem. Removal of pointers can improve the safety of code. It's much more difficult in C than something like C++, though, as C doesn't have many other options like references or smart pointers. Regardless, here are some thoughts on your code.

## Use Your `typedefs`

You've made a type definition for `struct person` named `Who`. But you only appear to be using it two of the five places where you need them. Many C programmers dislike using `typedef` with a `struct`. I am not one of those programmers. I think they make the code much nicer and easier to understand. You've made the `typedef`, so you should use it everywhere. `Person_create()` should return a `Who` not a `struct person`. Also in `main()` you should be creating 2 `Who`s, not 2 `struct person`s.

## Removing pointers

You've said the goal was to remove pointers from your `struct`, but you're still using one for the `name` field. Why? You could make it a fixed-length array if you truly want to remove all use of pointers. You'll need to ensure that you don't copy anything too long into it, in that case, though. You could define a constant for the maximum length of a name in that case. Something like this:

```
const size_t kMaxNameBytes = 32;    // Maximum number of bytes including NUL terminator

struct person {
    char name [ kMaxNameBytes ];
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

typedef struct person Who;
```

Now you have a `struct` that has no pointers. It is bigger, however. The disadvantage with having no pointers is that every `struct` must carry all of its data within the `struct` leading to much larger pieces of data on the stack. If you want an array of thousands of `person`s, it may be too large to fit on the stack.

As mentioned above, you'll also need to be more careful with your copies of the `name` field, now, too. Instead of just calling `w.name = strdup(name);`, you'll have to do something like this:

```
size_t name_len = MIN(strlen(name), kMaxNameBytes - 1);
memcpy(w.name, name, name_len);
w.name [ name_len + 1 ] = '\0';
```

Note all the extra work you now have to do to ensure that the string doesn't go over the maximum length and that it is also properly `NUL` terminated. On the other hand, copying a whole `person` is easier because you don't have to manually copy the `name` string like you do in your version. You can simply `memcpy()` the bytes from one `struct` to the `other` because it's self-contained.

## Handling Failure

Note that your code doesn't handle the failure of `strdup()`. If `strdup()` can't allocate the memory, it will return `NULL`. Your code doesn't check the return value and will happily set the name to `NULL` and keep going. This is likely to cause a memory error somewhere else in your program.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. How would I use a 'Who' instead of a 'struct person'? Think I originally tried that but didn't know how to do it.

Comment: You can simply replace any occurrence of `struct person` with `Who`. You can do a simple search and replace, for example.

Comment: so would be "Who ryan" for example?

Comment: Exactly! Often programmers will set the type name to be the same as the `struct` name without the word `struct`. So the type definition looks like `typedef struct person person;`. It's a little confusing, but it allows you to just write `person ryan`.

Answer (score 2):

## Memory management

Since you use `strdup` when initializing a person, you must free that memory when you are done with it.

## Naming things

You called the constructor `Person_create` and the other function `Print_person`. That's inconsistent since the verb should be in the same place in both cases. You should rename `Print_person` to `Person_print`, like it is already in the original code.

Comment: Thanks, the naming was an error. How do I free the memory in this instance? I know I used the Person_destroy function in the original code. Not sure how I'd do this in the second code

Comment: Just `free(who->name)`.